# How do I make a QBO v3 API Create, Update, and Delete Request with a JSON body

Tags: json, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm constructing my own HTTP requests for use with the QuickBooks Online v3 REST API, 'rolling my own' in the words of Keith Palmer - Consolibyt's response to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603227/3127764).

I particular, I want to create, update, and delete transactions and names using JSON-formatted request bodies. The documentation is very sparse with JSON examples, so [this](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/00100_requests_and_responses/0010_requests) is all I could find:

```
{
    ...
    "domain":"QBO"
    "sparse":{"true","false"}
    ...
}
```

The API gives XML examples for [creating](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/020_create), [updating](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/020_create), and [deleting](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/010_calling_data_services/060_delete) transactions, and I have been able to use those in the API explorer successfully. (For other reasons, though, I don't want to work with XML. I want to work in JSON.)

In trying to figure out how to do the same thing with JSON, I did a read of an existing JournalEntry (in the API Explorer), getting this response and planning to build the request body starting from here:

```
{
  "JournalEntry": {
    "Adjustment": false,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "1056",
    "SyncToken": "2",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-02-07T13:21:51-08:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-02-07T13:29:53-08:00"
    },
    "DocNumber": "4",
    "TxnDate": "2014-02-08",
    "CurrencyRef": {
      "value": "USD",
      "name": "United States Dollar"
    },
    "Line": [
      {
        "Id": "0",
        "Description": "test entry",
        "Amount": 102.0,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
          "PostingType": "Credit",
          "AccountRef": {
            "value": "57",
            "name": "Miscellaneous Income"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "Description": "test entry (UPDATED!)",
        "Amount": 252.0,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
          "PostingType": "Debit",
          "AccountRef": {
            "value": "29",
            "name": "6240 Miscellaneous"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "Description": "test entry",
        "Amount": 150.0,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
          "PostingType": "Credit",
          "AccountRef": {
            "value": "82",
            "name": "12100 Inventory Asset"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "time": "2014-02-07T14:21:16.181-08:00"
}
```

Here's the request body I'm using for an Update operation (on the same [JournalEntry page of the API Explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#JournalEntry)) -- note that I'm only changing the DocNumber (from 4 to 12345):

```
{
    "Adjustment": false,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "1056",
    "SyncToken": "2",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-02-07T13:21:51-08:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-02-07T13:29:53-08:00"
    },
    "DocNumber": "12345",
    "TxnDate": "2014-02-08",
    "CurrencyRef": {
      "value": "USD",
      "name": "United States Dollar"
    },
    "Line": [
      {
        "Id": "0",
        "Description": "test entry",
        "Amount": 102.0,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
          "PostingType": "Credit",
          "AccountRef": {
            "value": "57",
            "name": "Miscellaneous Income"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "Description": "test entry (UPDATED!)",
        "Amount": 252.0,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
          "PostingType": "Debit",
          "AccountRef": {
            "value": "29",
            "name": "6240 Miscellaneous"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "Description": "test entry",
        "Amount": 150.0,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
          "PostingType": "Credit",
          "AccountRef": {
            "value": "82",
            "name": "12100 Inventory Asset"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Here's the Response Body I get back:

```
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"An application error has occurred while processing your request","Detail":"System Failure Error: null","code":"10000"}],"type":"SystemFault"},"time":"2014-02-07T14:36:18.888-08:00"}
```

I'm also trying a sparse update, as per [these instructions](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/050_sparse_update), just to keep things simple. The request body:

```
{
    "sparse": "true",
    "Id": "1056",
    "SyncToken": "2",
    "DocNumber": "12345"
}
```

The response body I get back (in bright red):

```
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"An application error has occurred while processing your request","Detail":"System Failure Error: null","code":"10000"}],"type":"SystemFault"},"time":"2014-02-07T14:05:05.197-08:00"}
```

I have a feeling the problem here is something small. Can you point out what it is? Alternatively, if you have a **working** example of a JSON request body (for create, update, and delete operations of a transaction, ideally), that would be very helpful too (as hopefully I could use it as a template).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add Accept : application/json to your header.

Comment: THANK YOU, WILLIAM LORFING! That did the trick. I feel a little silly, but I can safely I wasn't going to catch that myself for a long time. I can't vote up the answer...hopefully someone else will.

Comment: Hii William,
I am getting same issue on any request body including default,
 Is there any Write restriction on Trial version of QuickBooks API?